# Rails serialization of Range of integers is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, range, yaml

I need to serialize ruby `Range`s using YAML, in a rails context.
I wanted to check if ranges of integers and ranges of strings were serialized properly.

Here was my test:

```rb
# classic irb
require 'yaml'         # => true
YAML::VERSION          # => "0.60"
YAML.dump(1..2)        # => "--- !ruby/range \nbegin: 1\nend: 2\nexcl: false\n"
YAML.dump("1".."2")    # => "--- !ruby/range \nbegin: \"1\"\nend: \"2\"\nexcl: false\n"
```

The two outputs are dutifully distinct, so I got forward and coded it inside my rails application.

However it seems that within a rails context, ruby forgets how to properly serialize a range of integers!

```rb
# ./script/rails console
Rails::VERSION::STRING # => "3.0.15"
RUBY_VERSION           # => "1.8.7"
YAML::VERSION          # => "0.60"
YAML.dump(1..2)        # => "--- !ruby/range\n  begin: 1\n  end: 2\n  excl: false"
YAML.dump("1".."2")    # => "--- !ruby/range\n  begin: 1\n  end: 2\n  excl: false"
# The two outputs are identical, the distinction between integers and strings is lost!
```

Both ruby and ruby on rails seem to use the same version of the YAML library.
If I don't get it wrong, my version of ruby doesn't support switching between multiple coder engines.

I have a few questions:

1. What is the cause of this difference?
2. Does this problem arise with newer versions of *ruby* / *rails*?
3. How could I fix that properly, in a compatible manner?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the value of YAML::ENGINE.yamler in the 2 cases?

Comment: `NameError: uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE` in both cases, I guess this is due to the <1.9 version of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

A range is a Ruby internal, not a YAML base type like an integer or string. Rather than encode the range as you are, use its start and end points and reconstruct the range on the receiving end.

I use something like:

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> range = 0..1
=> 0..1
[2] (pry) main: 0> require 'yaml'
=> true
[3] (pry) main: 0> YAML.dump(range)
=> "--- !ruby/range\nbegin: 0\nend: 1\nexcl: false\n"
[4] (pry) main: 0> YAML.dump({'min' => range.min, 'max' => range.max})
=> "---\nmin: 0\nmax: 1\n"
```

And then I can recreate the range on the receiving side using something like:

```
Range.new(*YAML.load(YAML.dump({'min' => range.min, 'max' => range.max})).values)
=> 0..1
```

or this if you're not sure that `'min'` and `'max'` will be in the right order:

```
[19] (pry) main: 0> Range.new(*YAML.load(YAML.dump({'min' => range.min, 'max' => range.max})).values_at('min', 'max'))
=> 0..1
```

---

Adding some information regarding Ruby 1.9.3+ serializing ranges of characters:

```
[2] (pry) main: 0> range = '0'..'1'
=> "0".."1"
[3] (pry) main: 0> YAML.dump(range)
=> "--- !ruby/range\nbegin: '0'\nend: '1'\nexcl: false\n"

[5] (pry) main: 0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
```

And again with 1.9.2+:

```
[2] (pry) main: 0> range = '0'..'1'
=> "0".."1"
[3] (pry) main: 0> YAML.dump(range)
=> "--- !ruby/range \nbegin: \"0\"\nend: \"1\"\nexcl: false\n"
[4] (pry) main: 0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
```

And, the workaround maintains the range start/end types:

```
[6] (pry) main: 0> Range.new(*YAML.load(YAML.dump({'min' => range.min, 'max' => range.max})).values_at('min', 'max'))
=> "0".."1"
```

In both cases the YAML_VERSION is `0.60`.

Comment: I'm serializing many different kind of objects, but when Ranges are present, they are the topmost object. So the only thing I could do in this sense would be to detect a Range and use a custom coding emulating YAML, and still use plain YAML for the other types... I'm not 100% pleased with that (as it is only a hack), but it could do the trick.

Comment: Btw I see that you have the same problem. Did you use pry in a rails console? What version of ruby, rails? and yaml are you using?

Comment: Ranges maintain their "type" when serialized in 1.9+. See the added information.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. The serialization occurs within ActiveRecord 3.0.15, using the `serialize` function. This version doesn't even let me provide a `dump` and `load` function on a class. The only solution I can think of would be to override the setter and substitute the value for a specially created `FixedYamlRange`.